# How to access UITableViewController variable from within a subclass'ed UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, layoutsubviews

How do I access `UITableViewController` parameter from within a subclass'ed `UITableViewCell`?

I have a parameter in the `UITableViewController` for the font size (i.e. users can change font size).  So the `layoutSubviews` method in my custom subclassed `UITableViewCell` will need to access the latest font when it needs to re-layout itself (as it label positions will depend on the font).

So my question, from with my custom subclassed `UITableViewCell`, and specifically within the `layoutSubviews` method, how do I access the "uiFont" parameter which is an instance variable from the `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the `UITableViewController` object from within your cell isn't a good approach in terms of design. What you should be doing is creating an ivar in the table cell itself to store the `UIFont` object:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    UIFont *font;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIFont *font;
```

And then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, set the font of the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [cell setFont:uiFont];
    ...
}
```

Comment: oh yes, I see what you mean indragie - will change my approach to this - thanks

Comment: oh actually what if the user changes the font size via the toolbar without scrolling the tableview? wouldn't this mean that "cellForRowAtIndexPath" might not be triggered?  If so the question then is how to (a) initiate a layout view callback, and (b) within layoutViews to get the new version of the font?

Comment: When the user changes the font, just call [tableView reloadData]. That'll call cellForRowAtIndexPath and update the font.

Comment: oh OK - and I guess somewhere in that mix layoutSubviews would be called also then?

Comment: I'm not sure if calling `reloadData` would automatically call `layoutSubviews` as well. Try calling just `reloadData` first and if that doesn't do it, add a `layoutSubviews` call after it.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do it: access the UITableViewController via a property on the application delegate (which you can access from anywhere using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate`), give the cell a reference to the UITableViewController when you create it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, or follow the UIResponder chain from the cell view until you find a UITableViewController.

But really, this is probably a poor architecture. You should probably just call `reloadData` on the table view to have it recreate all the cells, and set the font in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Or if the font setting should persist, you could store it in NSUserDefaults and have the cells listen for `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: I was wondering about the reloadData call & thinking it might be overkill - however considering the scenario I just thought of perhaps this is the best approach.  The scenario being: what if the user changes the font size via the toolbar without scrolling the tableview? wouldn't this mean that "cellForRowAtIndexPath" might not be triggered? If so the question then is how to (a) initiate a layout view callback, and (b) within layoutViews to get the new version of the font?

Comment: It would mean `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would not be triggered. Even worse, if they scroll slowly they could have half the cells on the screen with the old font and half with the new. You tell a view to lay itself out by sending it `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: ok then, based on this and the advice from indragie it seems like either the [tableView reloadData] is in order, or at least at the minimum setNeedsLayout - thanks for the help